# Web host delays in SQL updates

Tags: php, mysql

I am using VB.NET to call a PHP script that inserts a record into a table on a database hosted by my webspace provider.  Using their PHPMyAdmin tool, it shows up right away.  Using a remote tool like MySQL Workbench, it also shows up right away.

If I use another PHP script to retrieve that data, it will take 10 minutes for the record to show up.  Similarly, if I delete the record the PHP script to retrieve the data will still see it's there for about 10 minutes.  I suspect that copies of the database are "migrated" to different active copies to be accessed by PHP; probably for security reasons.

I'm somewhat new to PHP.  Is this a known "feature"?  Are there any ways to speed it up?

Thanks!

---

As requested, here are some additional details and clarifications:
Thanks.  Will try to be a bit more detailed and specific.  All php scripts and the database are hosted from my provider.

1. From VB I call a php script (myInsert.php) from the web provider's website to insert values into a table.  These values are passed to myInsert.php through the URL.  The record that is inserted has a field (UserID) that has a unique value.  The script returns a success when inserted.
2. I also have a php script (myCheckExist.php) that I run from VB that is also located on the web provider's website to check if a particular record exists that contains the UserID in question.  It then returns additional values that are associated with UserID.

If I run myInsert.php, then the inserted record becomes immediately visible using PHPMyAdmin or MySQLWorkbench.  It does not become visible to myCheckExist.php until 10 minutes later.  I have determined this by running the myCheckExist.php script at periodic intervals.  After 10 minutes, the inserted record becomes visible to myCheckExist.php.

Ten minutes later when the record is visible using myCheckExist.php, if I manually delete that record from the table using PHPMyAdmin and then run myCheckExist.php, the script continues to return that the record actually is still there for 10 minutes.  After that time, the myCheckExist.php script returns that the record is not there.

The code for myCheckExist is as follows:

```
//routine to check if the record with the UserID is present.  Returns true if it has, returns false if not

gc_collect_cycles();

    //Get the variables from the url line
    $USERID = $_GET['USERID'];

//include the key variables
//This comes from a file in the .htpasswds directory
    include '../.htpasswds/Progcfg.php';

    //Establish the connection to the database
$cxn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($cxn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $cxn->connect_error);
};

    //Build the SQL statement using the variables
$sqlstatement = "SELECT NumberPurchased FROM TableUserInfo WHERE USERID = '$USERID'";

//make the query
$result = $cxn->query($sqlstatement);

if ($result->num_rows >0) 
    {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $row[NumberPurchased];
    }
else
    {echo "False";
    }

    //close the connection
    mysqli_close($cxn);

//I tried adding these in case it was a buffer issue, but they didn't seem to do anything regarding the delay
unset($result);
gc_collect_cycles();
ob_end_clean();
?>
```

My thought is that PHPMyAdmin and remote tools like MySQL Workbench are pointed to a "live" database that is maintained in real time and that PHP scripts (for whatever reason) operate on a copy of the database that is updated every 10 minutes.

I contacted tech support at my hosting service, but they weren't sure about the delay and are unable to offer PHP programming support.

Please let me know if you need additional specific details.

Comment: Phpmyadmin as its name suggests, is written in php. So, there is no delay in php in obtaining anything. Your question lacks any details, so it is impossible to provide anything further.

Comment: It could be something simple like browser caching of the page. Can you check in the browser using developer tools (F12) whether you do indeed get a new page (result code 200), or if the page is fetched from the cache? And/or output a timestamp in myCheckExists.php so you can see whether you actually get a new page?

Comment: Sidenote: using `gc_collect_cycles` should not be necessary normally, and also `ob_end_clean` seems to be completely obsolete in this context. At the end of the script everything is cleaned and flushed.

Comment: Since called from a VB program, no real browser is involved.  I define a web browser service within VB, but that is cleared when stopping the VB program. Stopping and starting the VB program has had no effect on the 10 minute lag.  Timestamp is a great idea!  Will give that a try.

Comment: Fascinating results that support some delay occurring at the server.  Used only the following code: <?php echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A'); ?>   For the first 5 times it ran, the seconds updated.  After that, it didn't update until 10 minutes elapsed.  Seems to me that there is something in place to prevent malicious scripts from executing too frequently over a period of time.  If I renamed the script from checktime.php to checktime1.php and ran it again, I would get another 5 opportunities.